# process.stdout.write not working inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

Running in node.js, whenever I do something like

```
setTimeout(process.stdout.write, 200, "Test")
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'defaultEncoding' of undefined
```

I have tried to set

```
setTimeout(process.stdout.write.bind(this), 200, "Test")
```

Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `process.stdout.write(...)`, the context (`this`) inside of it is `process.stdout`.  When you pass it to `setTimeout`, this context gets lost.  As you noticed, `bind` is the correct way to fix this - but you need to bind to the right thing:

```
setTimeout(process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout), 200, "Test")
```